# Vue.js doesn't work in the bottom of my page, but works fine in the header

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Just wondering how come Vue.js isn't working on the bottom of the page but it works fine when embedded in the header. Is that supposed to happen or is it due to some script conflict? I have jquery also so maybe that's it.

Comment: Please add a jsfiddle

Comment: is the code in footer in document.ready

Comment: How do I know whether it's document ready?

Comment: you puncture it with a toothpick, if it's dry it's ready